# Remove square brackets from a String using Regular Expressions?

Tags: java, regex

How would I remove all square brackets ("[]") from a given String in Java?

```
String s = "[abcdefg]";
s = s.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

What regular expression would be used in this case?

Comment: Is this what you want: removing all `[]` regardless of whether they are in the middle of the string? Or remove only the matching `[]`? The answer may differ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this one:

```
 String s = "[abcdefg]";
 String regex = "\\[|\\]";
 s = s.replaceAll(regex, "");
 System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

you could match it using something like `"\\[([^\\]])\\]"` (opening brachet, a sequence of anything that isnt a closing bracket (encased inside `()` for later reference), followed by a closing bracket) and then replace the whole match (group 0) with the contents matched inside the `()` block (group 1)

Comment: hmm actually the OP never mentioned the brackets should be properly inlined

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - true, but seems like a logical assumption to me