# Java - replace all

Tags: java

I am getting all the user ids and I need to remove some characters.  I am adding them to an arraylist in a loop, but they are being added in this format:

```
"[a1234567]"
"[b1234567]"
```

I want to remove any `"` or `[` or `]` so it just leaves e.g. `a1234567`

I tried this:

```
userNumbers.add(link.getUserId().replaceAll("[\"\\[\\]]","") );
```

But nothing seemed to happen?

Comment: how are you retrieving from the list..?? or what is input the list.

Comment: I cannot modify link.getUserId() as its part of a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
userNumbers.add(link.getUserId().replaceAll(.replaceAll("\"\\[|\\]\"", ""));
```

Got it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15083671/3714122

Answer (score 4):

```
String userNumber = "\"[b1234567]\"";
System.out.println(userNumber.replaceAll("[\"\\[\\]]",""));
```

Output: `b1234567`

Why do you think that nothing seem to happen?

**Update**:

> Comment: Would performing a .toString() on an ArrayList cause this?

Source code `ArrayList.toString()` (inherited from `AbstractCollection`):

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```

You should loop the collection and print every single `String` or append them to one `String` if you don't want them like this `["b1234567"]`.

Comment: because I am passing it in the body of a POST, and retrieving it as a paramater at the other end.  It coming in like: "[b1234567]".  Would performing a .toString() on an ArrayList cause this?

Comment: Yes, it might from what I remember.

Answer (score 0):

```
String userNumber = "\"[b1234567]\"" ;
userNumber  = userNumber .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Using `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` RegExp in replaceAll method as argument then it colud be remove all characters except `a-z`, `0-9`, & `A-Z` ...

SO, Output is : `b1234567`